# Converting one hashmap to another by a flattening operation

Tags: java, java-8

If I have a mapping from `Map<User, List<Foo>>` map1 where Foo looks like below:

```
Foo
User
id
name
age
```

And id is unique across all Foos, I am looking for a way to convert the Map> to a map of `Map<Integer, Foo>` where the key is a foo id. I have tried the below but can only get to a mapping of `Map<Integer, List<Foo>>`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Foo>> idToListOfFoo = originalMap.values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getId));
```

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a collector for this. It is called [`toMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). You use it like this:

```
Map<Integer, Foo> idToListOfFoo = originalMap.values().stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId,  Function.identity()));
```

`toMap` takes 2 functions as parameteres: The first is used to get the key from the element and the second to get the value for the map.

[`Function.identity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) returns a function that just returns its input. Hence the key is the id and the value is the object itself in the resulting map.